# Idiom : too fond of one's own voice

Tags: idioms, exam-questions

What is the meaning of the idiom in bold part of given sentence ?

She is **too fond of her own voice**.

I tried to google its meaning but couldn't find its meaning anywhere .

It was asked in my exam and I have following four options to choose from :

A) loves singing

B) very selfish

C) doesn't listen properly to anyone else

D) very talkative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Oxford Learner's dictionary entry for fond](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/fond), "fond of doing something" can mean *liking to do something that other people find annoying or unpleasant, and doing it often*. Using that definition, "very talkative" would be the correct choice.

When we're using "fond" in that sense, we often (but not always) say something like "a little too fond" or "very fond".

> Albert is very fond of interrupting me when I speak.

A similar expression is "[like to hear oneself talk](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+to+hear+oneself+talk)": *[for someone] to enjoy one's own talking more than people enjoy listening to it.* That has the sense of talking just for the sake of making noise, or talking a lot but not saying anything interesting.

> Don't worry about the parts of the speech you missed — that guy just likes to hear himself talk.

A related expression is "[liking](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/liked+the+sound+of+one%27s+own+voice) (or [loving](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/love-the-sound-of-one-s-own-voice)) the sound of one's own voice". These both have the sense of being pompous or arrogant.

> Sherry just loves the sound of her own voice — she made a toast at dinner last night and spent 20 minutes talking about herself.

Answer (score 5):

Without additional context, the correct choice is

> very talkative

to the extent that no one else can get a word in.

> She likes listening to herself speak.